# Haskell labeling the nodes of a binary tree with my state monad does not work

Tags: haskell, binary, label, state, monads

So far I wrote the following code, I tested all the functions, and they work well, but testing the indexNodesM function, it just does not work, I think the put method is not working right.

The given test cases are:

```
execState (indexNodesM exTree1) 0 == 6
evalState (indexNodesM exTree1) 0 == Node (5,3) (Node (3,1) Leaf (Node (2,11) (Node (0,7) Leaf Leaf) (Node (1,5) Leaf Leaf))) (Node (4,13) Leaf Leaf)
```

For example, executing `execState (indexNodesM exTree1) 0` gives 0 as result.

My code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}


import Control.Monad (ap)


newtype State s a = S { runState :: s -> (a,s) }

evalState :: State s a -> s -> a
evalState (S f) s = fst (f s)

execState :: State s a -> s -> s
execState (S f) s = snd (f s)

instance Functor (State s) where
 fmap :: (a -> b) -> (State s a) -> (State s b)
 fmap f (S g) = S (\n -> (f (fst (g (n))), n))

instance Applicative (State s) where
  pure  = return
  (<*>) = ap 

instance Monad (State s) where
 return :: a -> (State s a)
 return a = S (\n -> (a, n))
 (>>=) :: (State s a) -> (a -> State s b) -> (State s b)
 (>>=) (S f) g   = S (\n -> runState (g (fst (f n))) (n))

get :: State s s
get = S (\n -> (n, n))

put :: s -> State s ()
put x = S (\n -> ((),x))

modify :: (a -> a) -> State a ()
modify f = S (\n -> ((),  f n))

data Tree a = Leaf | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

exTree1 :: Tree Int
exTree1 =
  Node 3
    (Node 1
      Leaf
      (Node 11
        (Node 7
          Leaf
          Leaf)
        (Node 5
          Leaf
          Leaf)))
    (Node 13
      Leaf
      Leaf)

indexNodesM :: Tree a -> State Int (Tree (Int, a))
indexNodesM Leaf = return Leaf
indexNodesM (Node x tree1 tree2) = do
 i <- get
 put (i + 1)
 t1 <- indexNodesM tree1
 t2 <- indexNodesM tree2
 return (Node (i, x) t1 t2)
```

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly does not work? Please clarify your problem and explain what your code tries to achieve.

Comment: Hello! I have tried to implement the state monad myself, which seems to work, and in the indexNodesM function I want to label the nodes of a binary tree, but as a result, all node is labeled with the starting state, for example: if i execute evalState (indexNodesM exTree1) 0 , then all nodes are labeled with 0, but it should be labeled with the numbers increasingly, like 0, 1, 2, 3 .. etc. I guess there is some problem with the put method, because it does not update the state in the indexNodesM function.

Comment: Please add this to your question. You can use edit to add clarifications.

Comment: Because your state monad "which seems to work" does not work at all.  Both your functor and your monad definition are broken and do not actually pass the state around at all.

Comment: You previously asked this in https://stackoverflow.com/q/61306856/7509065 but then deleted it. You should have undeleted it and edited the additional details back in, rather than creating a new question.

Comment: Forget the rest of your complexity, try to make a state monad work with a simple test such as `execState (const () <$> put True) False`.  What do you get?  What do you think you should get?  Now trace through your code and see why it is different.

Comment: You've gone quiet which I hope means you're thinking. I'll give you a pointer - every time you call `fst` or `snd` your are implicitly throwing away some information.  Is it ok to throw that information away?  What does that information represent and what should be done with it?

Comment: In your `>>=` definition your are using the same state (`n`) twice as the second parameter to `g`. Instead you should use `snd (f n)` since it  is the next new state.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you implement the `State` monad yourself?

Comment: @remmaks - Perhaps you could try to validate your client code within the official library state monad first. Next, you could port it to _your_ version of the state monad. In any case, it seems that your version of `fmap` drops the state update induced by the call to g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you fix the definition of your State monad, then it will work as you expect. The problem with your current implementation is that neither `>>=` nor `fmap` actually update the state, as you always use `fst` to throw the state away and then use the old state. Here is the corrected implementation:

```
import Control.Monad (ap, liftM)

...

instance Functor (State s) where
 fmap = liftM

instance Applicative (State s) where
  pure  = return
  (<*>) = ap

instance Monad (State s) where
 return :: a -> (State s a)
 return a = S (\n -> (a, n))
 (>>=) :: (State s a) -> (a -> State s b) -> (State s b)
 (>>=) (S f) g   = S (\n -> let (a, n') = f n in runState (g a) n')
```

Now your test cases work almost as expected, except that `indexNodesM` labels the nodes from left to right:

```
*Main> execState (indexNodesM exTree1) 0 == 6
True

*Main> evalState (indexNodesM exTree1) 0
Node (0,3) (Node (1,1) Leaf (Node (2,11) (Node (3,7) Leaf Leaf) (Node (4,5) Leaf Leaf))) (Node (5,13) Leaf Leaf)
```